# Convert byte[] to String, different result on windows and linux

Tags: java

In our program, we need to convert the character coded 253 to a String. The correct result should be "**ý**".

The code is like this:

```
 byte[] valueMarkByteArr = {(byte)253};
 valueMark = new String(valueMarkByteArr, "ISO-8859-1");
```

This works well in my Windows box. But when the code is deployed to server running on Linux, the result of valueMark is "**Ã½**". This breaks our program totally! "**Ã½**" is a two-character string!

I have tried many different ways of doing this (e.g. String.valueOf((char)253) 
 or Character.toString((char)253)), and the result is the same.
First of all, what affects the resulting string and make it different between those two different machines? How to make the correct string "ý" appear in the Linux platform?

BTW, in the Windows machine, java -version displays:
java version "1.8.0_102"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_102-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.102-b14, mixed mode)

On the Linux machine, it is:
openjdk version "1.8.0_131"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)

I have also wrote the following program to test on different machines. The Linux machine gives the same wrong result.

```
import java.io.*;

public class TestAttrMark {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      for (String s: args) {
         try {
            int argInt = Integer.parseInt(s);
            byte argByte = (byte) argInt;
            byte [] byteArr = new byte[] {argByte};

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("argInt: " + argInt);
        System.out.println("argByte: " + argByte + " or: 0x" + byteToHex(argByte));
        System.out.println("In ISO-8859-1: " + new String(byteArr, "ISO-8859-1"));
        System.out.println("In UTF8: " + new String(byteArr, "UTF8"));
        System.out.println("In ASCII: " + new String(byteArr, "ASCII"));
        System.out.println("In ISO8859_1: " + new String(byteArr, "ISO8859_1"));
        System.out.println("In ISO8859_2: " + new String(byteArr, "ISO8859_2"));
        System.out.println("In ISO8859_4: " + new String(byteArr, "ISO8859_4"));
        System.out.println("In Cp437: " + new String(byteArr, "Cp437"));
        System.out.println("In Cp850: " + new String(byteArr, "Cp850"));
        System.out.println("In Cp852: " + new String(byteArr, "Cp852"));

     } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
  }
   }

  private static String byteToHex(byte b) {
  // Returns hex String representation of byte b
  char hexDigit[] = {
     '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7',
     '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'
  };
  char[] array = { hexDigit[(b >> 4) & 0x0f], hexDigit[b & 0x0f] };
  return new String(array);
}   
}
```

After compiling, you can run with the following command:
     java -cp . TestAttrMark 253

Any suggestions are welcome! Thanks!

Comment: This displayed the correct character (ý) on both MacOs and Linux.

Comment: Could it be that your terminal is misconfigured? What are the `LC_ALL`/`LANG` environment variables set to?

Comment: Have the same correct result on my Ubuntu environment. `java version "1.8.0_121"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)`

Comment: The problem isn't converting byte[] to String, it appears when you try to print the string on the console. Probably the default charset (java) is UTF-8 in Linux but isn't it in the terminal. So print `Charset.defaultCharset()` to see whats the default charset in java.

Comment: This feels very much like a character encoding issue. The result looks very much like it has been through a cycle of UTF-8 encoding / decoding.

Comment: The special string "ý" serves as a delimiter when passing parameters to some third-party system. The third-party system gets the wrong string and the whole system fails totally. So it is not a problem of printing.

Comment: Any reason you just don't put `valueMark = "ý";` into your code? (Or "\u00fd", if you must?)

Comment: @shiuu can you pls post the code how you pass the string to the third-party system? It seems like the bug is there

Comment: @Edwardth       valueMark is the special string. appName and appVersion are strings. I use valueMark like this:
      String firstParam = appName + valueMark + appVersion;
Then pass firstParam to the api provided by the third-party. So there cannot be something wrong with this parameter passing.
      
      Luckily we can do some customisation on the third-party system. Now, I swap "Ã½" with "ý" in the customisation. That is my workaround for now. So it is no longer urgent. Thank you!